# displaying selected columns through ag grid by check boxes

Tags: angular, ag-grid

I am new to angular 6, and I had to display data in a tabular format so I went for ag grid.

```
  <div class = "row">
    <div class = "col s8">
<ag-grid-angular
    #agGrid
    style="width: 50vw; height: 20vw;" 
    class="ag-theme-balham"
    [rowData]="rowData" 
    [defaultColDef]="defaultColDef"
    [columnDefs]="columnDefs"
    [enableColResize]="true"
    [rowSelection]="rowSelection"
    [groupSelectsChildren]="true"
    [enableSorting]="true"
    [enableFilter]="true"
    [animateRows]="true"
    [autoGroupColumnDef]="autoGroupColumnDef"
    [suppressRowClickSelection]="true"
    >
</ag-grid-angular>
</div>
<div class="col s4">
        <label>
                <input [(ngModel)]="make" type="checkbox" />
                <span>Maker</span>
              </label><br>
        <label>
         <input [(ngModel)]="model" type="checkbox" />
        <span>Model</span>
            </label><br>
        <label>
             <input [(ngModel)]="price" type="checkbox" />
                 <span>Price</span>
            </label><br>
            <br>
            <a class="waves-effect waves-light btn" (click) ="Dynamo()"><i class="material-icons left">cloud</i>Save</a>
</div>
</div>
```

In ag-grid's documentation(sort of) they have a [grid](https://www.ag-grid.com/javascript-grid-filtering/) which does this, but I dont know what has to be added to implement that.

Check out the example called "Example Filter API" and you'll see clicking on column headers will show a tab like "||||" where you can select headers.if anyone knows how to add this functionality, help would be appreciated.

This is the code for my  component(app.component.ts). I have tried to mimic that feature by making checkbox addition for fields.(Dynamo() function)

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { AgGridModule } from 'ag-grid-angular';
import { FormsModule } from '@angular/forms';

const staticColumnDefs = [
  {headerName: 'Make', field: 'make',checkboxSelection: true},
  {headerName: 'Model', field: 'model' },
  {headerName: 'Price', field: 'price', editable: false}
];
const staticRowData = [
  { make: 'Toyota', model: 'Celica', price: 35000 },
  { make: 'Ford', model: 'Mondeo', price: 32000 },
  { make: 'Porsche', model: 'Boxter', price: 72000 },
  { make: 'Maruti', model: 'Suzuki', price: 0 },
  { make: 'Volkswagen', model: 'Loki', price: 2000 },
  { make: 'Pagani', model: 'Thanatos', price: 172000 }
];
@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent {
  make = false;
  model = false;
  price = false;
  title = 'app';
  defaultColDef = {
    width: 180,
    editable: true,
    filter: "agTextColumnFilter"
  };
  sideBar = 'filters';
   startColumn =0;
   endColumn = 0;
  columnDefs = staticColumnDefs;
    header = ['make','model','price'];
    rowSelection = "multiple";
    autoGroupColumnDef = {
      headerName: "Make",
      field: "make",
      width: 200,
      cellRenderer: "agGroupCellRenderer",
      cellRendererParams: { checkbox: true }
    };

  rowData = staticRowData;
  Dynamo(){
    var arr = [];
    arr.push(this.make);
    arr.push(this.model);
    arr.push(this.price);
    var tempColumnDefs = [];
    var tempRowData = [
      { make: 'Toyota', model: 'Celica', price: 35000 },
      { make: 'Ford', model: 'Mondeo', price: 32000 },
      { make: 'Porsche', model: 'Boxter', price: 72000 },
      { make: 'Maruti', model: 'Suzuki', price: 0 },
      { make: 'Volkswagen', model: 'Loki', price: 2000 },
      { make: 'Pagani', model: 'Thanatos', price: 172000 }
    ];
    for( var i = 0;i<staticColumnDefs.length;i++)
      {
        if(arr[i])
        {tempColumnDefs.push(staticColumnDefs[i]);}
      }
      for( var i = 0;i<tempRowData.length;i++)
      {
        for(var j = 0;j<this.header.length;j++)
        {
          if(!arr[j])
          {
            console.log(j);
            delete tempRowData[i][this.header[j]];
          }
        }
      }

      this.columnDefs = tempColumnDefs;
   this.rowData = tempRowData;
   tempRowData = []
  }
}
```

I apologize if this question is too silly or noob-y.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

About [`column header menu`](https://www.ag-grid.com/javascript-grid-column-menu/), it could be accessed via `menuTabs` property of `columnDef`:

```
menuTabs: ["filterMenuTab", "generalMenuTab", "columnsMenuTab"]
```

> 1. `generalMenuTab`: Include in the `menuTabs` array to show the main panel.
> 2. **`filterMenuTab`**: Include in the `menuTabs` array to show the filter panel.
> 3. `columnsMenuTab`: Include in the `menuTabs` array to show the column selection panel.

Second point exactly what you need.

Also, the `filter` menu could be accessed on [`ToolPanel`](https://www.ag-grid.com/javascript-grid-tool-panel-filters/)

Just append `[sideBar]="sideBar"` attribute on html and define it like : `this.sideBar = "filters";`, same property could be accessed directly via `gridOptions.sideBar`

Comment: I studied that part but as I said before that specific feature i am unable to add. I have added the component code in problem so if you know exactly how to add it, try it.